# Rating a game within the app using game center

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, game-center

I'm currently developing an iOS game with SpriteKit using Swift, and I'm looking at different capabilities I could implement in my app. As I've seen in many games, you can rate a game without leaving the app within game center. Here's an example:

[image]

However, I've thoroughly searched how this works and how to implement it (as well as the Facebook Liking) without finding results. Even Apple's GameKit [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit#overview) doesn't seem to even mention this. Moreover, it seems really weird that I can rate and click done as many times as I want on the game center screen. So, is it possible to rate a game without leaving the app using game center?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'll have to configure your app for game center and use `GKGameCenterViewController()` to get a view controller and present it to display that screen. You may also need to implement the `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate` protocol.

Read the Game Center Programming Guide for more info:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: If it does work, why does it seem to let me rate the app as many times as I want?

Comment: Users can change their App Store ratings any time they want…